# Find User's Groups Using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

My fetch request is getting all the group objects rather than the ones I want.

I want it to **fetch only the groups that the current user is a part of**, but my predicate does not seem to be working. Any thoughts to what's wrong?

```
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AGroup" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext]];
    AUser *u = [AUser currentUser];  //gets app's current user
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY users = %@", u]];
```

I have also tried the following, which did not work:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(users CONTAINS %@)", u];
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(users, $user, $user = %@).@count = [users count]", u];
```

Class Structure

```
AGroup
- users (Type: AUser *)

AUser
- name (Type: NSString *)
```

Comment: Is `users` a relationship from AGroup to AUser? Then `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY users = %@", u]` should work if I am not mistaken. But the easier solution is to define the inverse relationship `groups` from AUser to AGroup. Then you just do `u.groups`

Comment: There is actually a u.groups style relationship, I just never mentioned in the question

Comment: So you could use `u.groups` to get all groups of the user.

Comment: Ok. Will do. Not sure why the predicate didn't work, but u.groups is definitely a better solution. Do you want to write it as answer so that I can accept it and you can get points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see why

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY users = %@", u]
```

does not work for you, but the easier solution is just to use the inverse relationship

```
AUser *u = [AUser currentUser];
NSSet *theGroups = u.groups;
```

or, if you need it as an array:

```
NSArray *theGroups = [u.groups allObjects];
```

Comment: Just realized that my `setCurrentUser` method is glitchy

Comment: Actually my method is correct, I was just calling it in the wrong if statement.